# Invert a symmetric partition matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

How do I invert this matrix?

$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \mathbf{x'} \\ \mathbf{x} & I \end{bmatrix} $$

If $X$ is $n \times n$, then $I$ is the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ identity and $x \in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ is a vector.

Thanks

Comment: In this case, I think it's actually fruitful to _construct_ the inverse matrix using the algorithm "Do row operations to your matrix until it is the identity matrix, then do the same row operations to the identity matrix", or at the very least, assume that $X^{-1} =\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & \mathbf{y'} \\ \mathbf{y} & M \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ do the multiplication $XX^{-1}$ and solve the systems of equations you get.

Comment: What is "x' " ?

Comment: @Peter The transpose of $\mathbf x$.

Comment: You may use Schur complement to invert the matrix, but in the present case, since the identity matrix commutes with everything, it is not hard to solve $XY=I$ directly. Note that as $X$ is symmetric, its inverse must also be symmetric.

Comment: To be specific, do the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ by hand; for $n=2,$ your $x$ is a single number, call it $a.$ For $n=3,$ your $x'$ is a pair of numbers, say $x' = (a,b)$ and $x$ is the column. If that is too hard, pick some numbers you like for $(a,b),$ then some different numbers.

Comment: @user3294195: Check out the section "Block matrix inversion" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Shermann-Morrison formula and the section "Block matrix inversion" at 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix we can infer the following.

$X^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \frac{x^\intercal x}{1-x^\intercal x} & -x^\intercal - \frac{x^\intercal x}{1-x^\intercal x} x^\intercal \\ -x - \frac{x^\intercal x}{1-x^\intercal x} x & I_{n-1} + \frac{1}{1-x^\intercal x} x x^\intercal\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ as  $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x^{'} \\ x & I_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$, with $x = (x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)^{'}$. Then apply the follwing row operations: 
\begin{align}
& R_i - x_iR_1 & \forall i \geq 2, \\
& \frac{1}{1-x_i^2}R_i & \forall i \geq 2, \\
& R_1 - x_iR_i & \forall i \geq 2.
\end{align} Then we have found that $A$ is the product of $(n-1)$ + $(n-1)$ + $(n-1) = 3(n-1)$ elementary matrices $E_j$, and $$A^{-1} = \left( \prod_{j}^{3(n-1)} E_j \right)^{-1}.$$